# AppCenter export got automatically disabled

Tags: azure-application-insights, visual-studio-app-center

We've enabled for 2 app's (IOS and Android) the export to application insights, we are running some dashboards on the exported data.

This week we noticed that the export to application insights was simultaneously disabled on both app's.
It's not a manual action as the ingress stopped abrupt at 10PM.

We are wondering how this can happen, we cannot find any audit log's, are there certain events, did we hit a threshold?

Comment: To check if the threshold is hit, you can go to application insights -> Usage and estimated costs -> check the usage and daily cap.

Comment: The daily cap is set to 100 GB / day, the current ingress is 25 - 30 MB / day

Comment: @msjonathan Any luck here?

Comment: No, Daily cap is not the issue - I've contacted the AppCenter support for this

Comment: @msjonathan Any update from AppCenter support? We had seemingly the exact same thing happen for our app (export to App Insights disabled mysteriously) and have also contacted MS. 
Interestingly, for us we have about 10 instances of AppCenter/AppInsights and only 2 of the exports were disabled.

Comment: Yes, it was an internal issue and they deployed some changes and we had to enable the export again afterwards. Currently we have an alert on Application Insights that checks the ingress of data - just so we can create a support case when it happens again.